# Rename "Have A Promotional Code?" in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

check please: http://www.baroniarialb.cat/finalitza-la-compra/
I have AVADA and Woocommerce theme installed, but I need to change the "Have A Promotional Code?" and I can't find the correct code to do it.
I have already tried different ways that appear on the internet without success from funtions.php.
Could you guide me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code. I've tested from the my side and it's working fine

```
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_cart( $translated_text, $text, $text_domain ) {
    
    if ( is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $text_domain ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }
    if ( 'Apply Coupon' === $text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Put your text here'; //Here add your text which you want to replace
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'changetext', 'woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_cart', 10, 3 );
```

You can change via **jQuery** also. Add the script in the footer.php file

```
<script>
jQuery("h2.promo-code-heading").text("Hello world!");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but dont work for me... This is my funtions.php

Comment: I've update my ans with jquery so please check that @nibfreelancer

Comment: No, if I put  jQuery code I get an error on the web. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've updated my answer please check that it's working fine on your website check this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/1hghugt

Comment: Thanks my friend, but when copy and paste this code mi site es broken: https://prnt.sc/1hhast4

Comment: Where do you add the script? @nibfreelancer

Comment: In this rute: 
ftp://baroniarialb2@ftp.baroniarialb.cat/httpdocs/wp/wp-content/themes/Avada/functions.php

Comment: Script need to add in footer file not in function file @nibfreelancer

Answer (score -1):

For strings translations on plugins, we use the locotranslate plugin, simple, fast and can use translated files for more wordpress instances.